# Command not found error - cogs - discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I tried adding cogs to my code in order to make it a bit cleaner, but I quickly ran into an odd problem; let me show you a sample of my code which I've singled out:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import json

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='s!', intents=intents)

@client.command()
async def load(ctx,extension):
   client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
   if True:
      await ctx.channel.send('Module successfully loaded.')

@client.command()
async def unload(ctx,extension):
   client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
   if True:
      await ctx.channel.send('Module successfully unloaded.')

@client.command()
async def reload(ctx,extension):
   client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
   client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
   if True:
      await ctx.channel.send('Module successfully reloaded.')

if os.path.exists(os.getcwd() + '/config.json'):

  with open('./config.json') as f:
   configData = json.load(f)
else:
  configTemplate = {'Token': '', 'Prefix': 's!'}

  with open(os.getcwd() + '/config.json', 'w+') as f:
    json.dump(configTemplate, f)

token = configData['Token']
prefix = configData['Prefix']

@client.command(pass_context=True)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  await client.wait_until_ready()

  for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
     if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

 print('{0.user} systems online!'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
   if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
     await ctx.send('This command does not exist.')

client.run(token)
```

This is my main.py file.

And this is my cog:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Example(commands.Cog):

def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    username = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
    user_message = str(message.content)
    channel = str(message.channel)
    print(f'{username}: {user_message} ({channel})')


    if message.author == self.client.user:
        return

    if user_message.lower() == 's!hello':
        await message.channel.send(f'Hello {username}!')
        return

def setup(client):
client.add_cog(Example(client))
```

Problem is, when I run the code and type 's!hello' in my test Discord server - the error block which contains 'This command does not exist.' runs and gives me that error message in the server; it's essentially saying that the command doesn't exist, even though I believe everything is imported correctly.

What's the problem here? And how can this issue be fixed? Thanks!

Edit: So after changing the location of my cog python file into a new location and importing that in, the bot now actually sends the 'Hello' message - but quickly follows it up with 'This command does not exist.', so it now sends 2 messages instead of the intended 1.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a [mcve] (emphasis on *minimal*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says that obviously because there is no command called 'hello'. Since the bot first checks for a prefix in the message(s! in your case), hence anything after that is considered to be a command name. You need to implement a command first instead. So your cog file would go something like this

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Example(commands.Cog):

def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    username = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
    user_message = str(message.content)
    channel = str(message.channel)
    print(f'{username}: {user_message} ({channel})')


    if message.author == self.client.user:
       return
    # I removed code from here since that was not required


@commands.command() # Actually introducing a command.
async def hello(self, ctx:commands.Context)
      await ctx.send(f'Hello {ctx.author}')

def setup(client):
client.add_cog(Example(client))
```

The problem with your code was that

```
if user_message.lower() == 's!hello':
    await message.channel.send(f'Hello {username}!')
    return
```

This checked for messages containing 's!hello', but since it contains 's!' it is considered as a call to the bot. Thus, the message check event is not executed. And hence the command not found error.